# Always staying behind at work - sign of bad project management?

Tags: project-management, time-management

Leaving work at my contractual end of play time seems to be a rare event. Usually work has to be done that requires working an hour over the end of the day, or a meeting (time differences are a real pain).

Is there anything I can do to avoid this? I already make sure I don't start a task in for the end of the day (or the end of the next day), which I cannot finish within that time.

Is this a sign of bad project management? Also, how do Project Managers handle time zones (they are a real inconvenience)?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

> Is there anything I can do to avoid
>   this?

Sure, leave on time. Task not done? Start on it when you arrive on time the next working day.

Manager doesn't like this? That's his (or her) problem. Scheduling tasks, assigning priorities, and managing resources is the managers job. Doing your tasks to the best of your ability within the contractually agreed upon working hours is your job.

Constantly asking you to stay late or work on weekends or holidays is either poor management or lack of company resources (not enough people to do the job). *Requiring* you to stay beyond the statutory limit without paying overtime is a violation of labor laws.

(Of course this assumes you are an hourly employee.)

Answer (score 1):

It could be that they simply don't have enough people on the job, and there's too much in the role you're doing for one person to get through in a day. That said, I find that I'll often get engaged with something at work, not notice the time, and end up leaving somewhat late. This is more that I'm enjoying it at a given moment, than it is to do with that extra time being strictly necessary. I think this is something that you need to ask yourself about. Is more being asked of you than you can get done in your contract hours? If so, why? Do you really enjoy what you do, and spend time trying to do it as well as possible?

On the time zones thing, they are a nightmare. Sometimes you need to have a conversation with someone who wakes up not long before you want to head home, and someone's going to have to take the awkward time (or more usually, a compromise must be reached). There's no perfect answer to this, since someone is always going to have to be available at a time they rather wouldn't. I think the most important thing is to ensure it's at the least inconvenient time for all parties involved.